# RDLC reports are not published to after deployed to IIS?

Tags: vb.net, report, rdlc, web-deployment

I have a web application written in VB.NET. In my application I have a few RDLC reports that will be generated dynamically. Everything works fine during the development. But those reports are not working after I deployed my web application to IIS. Here are my problems.

(1) All the reports under my RDLC folder are not deployed, I think this is the reason why I got the error “error occurred during local report processing”
My question is why this folder was not published, and what should I set to publish this folder?

(2) If I manually copy those RDLC reports to the destination folder,  I got  another error “failure: unknown user name or bad password” 
My authentication mode is set to Windows. Is there anything else I need to set in my web.config?

I am using IIS 5.1 and my web app has been upgraded from VS2005 to VS2010.

Answer (score 8):

Your RDLC files are probably marked as "Embedded resource".
Right click on rdlc file and change it to "Content" and re-publish.
It will work this time.